# How to do video recording?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-webcam-plugin

I want to record a video using jquery and flash using the systems's Webcam.
I googled a lot and found only scriptcam that could help me. I tried to integrate it with my webapp but the problem I face is that the scriptcam plugin hangs on `document load`. The live stream freezes with the first image it captured.

Can anyone help me finding a plugin that works just fine to capture a video using webcam and store it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC), however it does not future a fall back to Flash, so the browser support might be a bit limited.

Comment: There is [MediaStreamRecorder.js](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder) which has flash/opentok based fallbacks; however not sure if these fallbacks works in the moment.

Comment: @MuazKhan: The flash fallback only works for audio I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this would be done via Flash, not javascript, due to browser compatibility.

That said, [html5rocks has a decent tutorial, and also explains some of the technical challenges](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Mainly:

> The real problem is that the web's security model is very different from the native world. For example, I probably don't want every Joe Shmoe web site to have random access to my video camera. It's a tough problem to get right.